# How to perform default double click action on customised NSToolbarItem with label

Tags: cocoa, operating-system, nstoolbaritem

I have created a custom toolbar using storyboard which contain a toolbar item with label and buttons. The default double click action to zoom and zoom out(enlarging and minimising the window size) in toolbar is working except the label area.
How to make it work on label area also.

Comment: Does double click on a button or the label of a standard item zoom?

Comment: I want to Keep the default NSToolbar double click action. But it's not happening when I add label to the toolbar, that area is not working.

Comment: Does `NSToolbar` have a double click action? Double-click a window's title bar to zoom is a preference of the Dock and double-click on a toolbar item doesn't work in the Finder. Is the toolbar item a custom item with a view?

Comment: am hiding the default window title and showing custom title in toolbar. I want to perform the same double click action in this label also. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try to implement the double click action in the title view?